# Python Scrapy spider is crawling the url, but returns nothing

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to parse [site](https://www.gismeteo.ru/diary/4368/2019/6/).
It's my first project with scrapy and i'm a beginner in python.
Using this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-crawl-a-web-page-with-scrapy-and-python-3#step-2-%E2%80%94-extracting-data-from-a-page), I crawled one url and didn't get any data from it.

I tried some different xpath queries and changed the USER_AGENT in settings, but it still return nothing.

This is the part of code that describes what i'm trying to parse:

```
        def parse(self, response):
    SET_SELECTOR = '.set'
    for brickset in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):

        TITLE_SELECTOR= '//head//title/text'
        DATE_SELECTOR= '//table/tbody[2]//td[2]//text()'
        TEMP_SELECTOR= '//table/tbody[2]/tr[1]/td[1]//text()'
        yield {
            'title': brickset.xpath(TITLE_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            'date': brickset.xpath(DATE_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            'temp1':brickset.xpath(TEMP_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
        }
```

This is the data from the command line:

```
 DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.gismeteo.ru/diary/4368/2019/6/> (referer: None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just set the wrong selector. I've tested it for you:

```
    def parse(self, response):
        TITLE_SELECTOR= '//div[@id="page_title"]//text()'
        DATE_SELECTOR= '//table//tbody[1]//text()'

        yield {
            'title': response.xpath(TITLE_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            'date': response.xpath(DATE_SELECTOR).extract(),
        }
```

Comment: Since you said you are new to Python, I would suggest you take a look at [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) and [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). The website you are trying to crawl is purely static, and these two are more suitable for a starter. Scrapy is probably overkill for you now.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works! 
I started to study bs4 + requests, but read somewhere that Scrapy is more functional and decided to try it out.